# "Malformed json" error while running predictionIO

Tags: predictionio

I was trying universal recommender using predictionIO. While importing .json file into the app by command:

```
$ pio import --appid 6 --input importdata/click.json
```

I am getting an error:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2][ERROR] [FileToEvents$] 
malformed json => {"id":59, "person_id":2530, "association_id":2101, "post_id":76901, "interaction":"2016-04-16 13:49:12.550", "type":2},
[ERROR] [FileToEvents$] 
malformed json => {"id":137836, "person_id":10385, "association_id":2264, "post_id":192841, "interaction":"2017-03-26 22:07:46.507", "type":1},
[ERROR] [Utils] Aborting task
```

Is this because of the json file that I imported. But the json file is valid with no errors. Is the universal recommender have any kind of format for the input json?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with predictinIO. Check whether the json is in correct format. If so, then check the key values in the json and make sure there as required.

[Reference](http://actionml.com/docs/ur_input)